# UIView Bounds attribute is null

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, uiview

I don't know why, but the bounds of my view are 0. I created a IBOutlet and when   I access the bounds: self.openGLView.bounds the height and width are 0 even though in Interface Builder the size isn't 0 (I mean, the view appears to be larger than 0). Why is so ?

Comment: Are you using Autolayout? at what point are you checking the bounds? Is self.openGLView not nil at this point?

Comment: how you are retrieving the values?

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", self.openGLView); If that's null, then the bounds will be, too.